# EmailtoCase attaching to wrong contact

Tags: email2case

I have Email to case in place which was working perfectly. ALl of a sudden the new cases created by Email2case is attaching to a wrong contact. It is the first contact in the contact list. I am not able to understand why its happening? Please help me if any of you have experienced similar situation.

Comment: Do you have any triggers in the system doing this?

Comment: No Triggers @MohithShrivastava

Comment: Presumably you have read [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385630&type=1). Check also for before save/after save flows